# Load a text file from the same directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, playframework

I'm working with Play Framework (using the port 9000). When I use Ajax indicating the URL to a txt I try to indicate it in the following way:

```
...
<script>
        var fileContent;
        $.ajax({
            url : "http://localhost:9000/text.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            ...
</script>
...
```

The text file "text.txt" is on the same folder as the html file that calls it. However, when I try to access it, I just can't in this way. I did set up Apache yesterday to test it and I did try typing

```
            http://localhost/text.txt
```

in the web browser and it loads, but when I do that with Play, it does not allow me. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: You are querying that file on port 9000 - is that where you are serving it? Opening `http://localhost/text.txt` in your browser will use port 80 by default. Maybe you are just specifying the wrong port.

Comment: What response code(s) are you getting in the http response from the ajax call. Might help?

Comment: I type localhost without including the 9000 port just when I try it with Apache, but when I do it with the play framework in the html file I indicate the port 9000 as I have written to make sure that it loads the file from the port used by Play :/

Comment: I get:
GET http://localhost:9000/text.txt
 
404 Not Found
  61ms 
jquery.min.js (línea 5)
HeadersResponse

Not found

GET /text.txt

 

0

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:9000/text.txt"